# Can you actually do a road-trip in Greenland?

Tags: road-trips, extreme-tourism, greenland

There is of course the epic Top Gear episode where they went for the [North Pole](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WNkvASxfEWQ).

I came across this short [youtube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lr47w7Tz5-U) film on some driving the only "freeway" in Greenland. It seems you can drive on Greenland if you are not supported by a television network. Google maps don't show a road map.

So can I do a road-trip in Greenland and where do I need to go?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

[Unfortunately no](http://wikitravel.org/en/Greenland#Get_around), according to Wikitravel.

> There is no road or rail system. The easiest way to get around
>   Greenland is by plane, particularly Air Greenland. In the summer,
>   Arctic Umiaq Line passenger ships provide service to destinations
>   between Narsarsuaq and Uummannaq along the west coast.

Of course, if you got a skidoo or dog sled, you could make your own way around ;)

Wikipedia actually has more information - [Transport in Greenland](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_in_Greenland)

> The transportation system in Greenland is very unusual in that
>   Greenland has no railways, no inland waterways, and virtually no roads
>   between towns.

It goes into further detail about the few roads that do exist:

> There are 150 km (90 mi) of roads in the whole country; 60 km (40 mi)
>   of the roads are paved. Two towns are connected by a 4.5 km road,
>   Ivittuut and Kangilinnguit; the rest are isolated.

Answer (score 8):

An Arctic Circle Road between Sisimiut and Kangerlussuaq is under consideration, and a 126 km long ATV track [was completed in September 2021](https://traveltrade.visitgreenland.com/latest-news/paving-new-futures-with-the-arctic-circle-road/):

[image: Map of Arctic Circle Road]
*[Source](https://web.archive.org/web/20221202090805/https://polarnews.ch/arktis/menschen-politik/1205-spatenstich-fuer-groenlands-erste-strasse-zwischen-siedlungen).*

You can probably drive it with a guided ATV tour.

The solid line is the ATV track.  The dashed line is the Arctic Circle Trail, a popular hiking (trekking/backpacking) trail.  Maybe you can even organise a one-way ATV tour and hike back?