# Is it possible to get from Canada to Greenland by road or ferry?

Tags: canada, road-trips, ferries, greenland

Are there any roads (or ferry service) that would allow a person to travel from Canada to Greenland without taking a plane?

Comment: Get a Jeep or something and drive over the ice from Ellesmere Island (Canada) to Etah (Greenland);-P Not sure how thick the ice is though (or other practicalities of driving around there in a 4WD), but that's the route some of the Inuit took in the past to get to Greenland, [according to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Etah%2C_Greenland).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

[The Greenland tourist board says No](http://www.greenland.com/en/plan-your-trip/how-to-get-to-greenland/).

> **There are no ferry connections between Greenland and Iceland, Denmark or Canada.** However, more and more cruise shipping companies are choosing to include Greenland on their itineraries, whereby it is possible to begin the voyage from Iceland or go onboard at, for example, Kangerlussuaq.

Greenland being an island, I hope it is obvious that there are no roads linking it to a continent. While theoretically the sea freezes, the ice is not traversable by anyone other than a well-prepared team equipped for arctic exploration.

Comment: @Vince Thanks for the edit, but actually "[There are no roads](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/7628/can-you-actually-do-a-road-trip-in-greenland?rq=1)" is a fairly accurate summary of the situation.